# Examples of sequences bounded and unbounded in probability

Tags: probability

I am studying mathematical statistics and am learning about the concept of a sequence being 'bounded in probability'. A sequence of random variables $X_1 , X_2, ..., X_n$ is bounded in probability if $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M >0$ such that $P(|X_n|>M)<\epsilon$ for all $n$. Could anyone please provide me with some examples of $X_1 , X_2, ..., X_n$ that are bounded in probability and some that are not? If $X_1 , X_2, ..., X_n$ has bounded support then it must be bounded in probability, right?

Comment: Any finite number of r.v.'s is bounded in probability.

Answer (score 2):

$X_n=n$ defines a sequence which is not bounded in probability: $P(|X_n|>M)=1$ when $n >M$.

Any unformly bounded sequence is bounded in probability. A useful result says that $(X_n)$ is bounded in probability if it converges in distribution.

Incidentally, another term for '$(X_n)$ is bounded in probability' is '$(X_n)$ is tight'.